# Looping over urls to do the same thing

Tags: javascript, loops, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I am tring to scrape a few sites. Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    url = urls[i];
    console.log("Start scraping: " + url);

    page.open(url, function () {
        waitFor(function() {
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.getElementById("progressWrapper").childNodes.length == 1;
            });

        }, function() {
            var price = page.evaluate(function() {
                // do something
                return price;
            });

            console.log(price);
            result = url + " ; " + price;
            output = output + "\r\n" + result;
        });
    });

}
fs.write('test.txt', output);
phantom.exit();
```

I want to scrape all sites in the array urls, extract some information and then write this information to a text file.

But there seems to be a problem with the for loop. When scraping only one site without using a loop, all works as I want. But with the loop, first nothing happens, then the line

```
console.log("Start scraping: " + url);
```

is shown, but one time too much.
If url = {a,b,c}, then phantomjs does:

```
Start scraping: a 
Start scraping: b 
Start scraping: c 
Start scraping:
```

It seems that page.open isn't called at all.
I am newbie to JS so I am sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: Trying adding `console.log("Scraping " + urls.length + " pages.")` prior to the scraping, and potentially surround the URL in quotes when you log it. You may have empty (or whitespace-only) input in the list.

Answer (score 4):

PhantomJS is asynchronous. By calling `page.open()` multiple times using a loop, you essentially rush the execution of the callback. You're overwriting the current request before it is finished with a new request which is then again overwritten. You need to execute them one after the other, for example like this:

```
page.open(url, function () {
    waitFor(function() {
       // something
    }, function() {
        page.open(url, function () {
            waitFor(function() {
               // something
            }, function() {
                // and so on
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But this is tedious. There are utilities that can help you with writing nicer code like [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). You can install it in the directory of the phantomjs script through npm.

```
var async = require("async"); // install async through npm
var tests = urls.map(function(url){
    return function(callback){
        page.open(url, function () {
            waitFor(function() {
               // something
            }, function() {
                callback();
            });
        });
    };
});
async.series(tests, function finish(){
    fs.write('test.txt', output);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

If you don't want any dependencies, then it is also easy to define your own recursive function (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31188699)):

```
var urls = [/*....*/];

function handle_page(url){
    page.open(url, function(){
        waitFor(function() {
           // something
        }, function() {
            next_page();
        });
    });
}

function next_page(){
    var url = urls.shift();
    if(!urls){
        phantom.exit(0);
    }
    handle_page(url);
}

next_page();
```