# Downloading multiple URLs through phantomjs in R. How can I loop over them?

Tags: r, loops, url, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to download several URLs through R using pahtomjs as the websites contain javascript. I am able to download a single webpage using the code in the last code box below, but I need it to work for multiple websites. To find that code i used this tutorial: http://flovv.github.io/Scrape-JS-Sites/
 I have a character string of urls, urls[i], and one for the destinations where they should be saved urls[i]. 
Previously I tried:

```
for(i in seq_along(urls)) {
 download.file(urls[i], destinations[i], mode="wb")
}
```

However, this didn't work as the websites contain javascript.

I tried to follow the answers in this post but was quite confused: [Scraping multiple URLs by looping in PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120421/scraping-multiple-urls-by-looping-in-phantomjs)

```
writeLines("var url = 'url link';
var page = new WebPage();
var fs = require('fs');

page.open(url, function (status) {
        just_wait();
});

function just_wait() {
    setTimeout(function() {
               fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
            phantom.exit();
    }, 2500);
}
", con = "scrape.js")

js_scrape <- function(url = "url link", 
                      js_path = "scrape.js", 
                      phantompath = "phantomjs"){
  lines <- readLines(js_path)
  lines[1] <- paste0("var url ='", url ,"';")
  writeLines(lines, js_path)

  command = paste(phantompath, js_path, sep = " ")
  system(command)

}

js_scrape()
```

Please help me!