# How to write synchronous JavaScript code for PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, promise, synchronous

I have learned programming asynchronous PhantomJS code, but now I am planning to write synchronous JavaScript. I have known promise can do this.

How can I write synchronous JavaScript code for PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1):

> I am planning to write synchronous JavaScript. I have known promise can do this.

That's not exactly true. Promises still require asynchronous programming, but they are good to escape the callback hell.

> How can I write synchronous JavaScript code for PhantomJS?

The PhantomJS API uses callbacks to work. It doesn't emit promises that you can use. Of course you could write a wrapper around PhantomJS to support a promise-like API, but that would be overkill. Have a look at [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) which is built on top of PhantomJS (and Slimer.js) and does provide an API similar to the promise syntax, but there are differences. I have [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129100/1816580) that shows some intricacies of using CasperJS.

Comment: Is there any way to use thirdparty components like step or async ? Just like nodejs.

Comment: Yes, you can use async in PhantomJS. PhantomJS' API module system is completely different from node.js, but it has one.

Comment: Can you show some examples? I have not got async module in src/modules of phantomjs source codes.

Comment: Just install async.js through npm and require it. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681464/looping-over-urls-to-do-the-same-thing) is an application example.

Comment: I use phantomjs in windows.
Can i compile async.js in phantomjs or require it as thirdparty components?

Comment: You don't compile JavaScript code, but other than that yes.